How can I convert a spannableStringBuilder to integer in java on android without the app crashing?
So I am a highschool student (relevant cause I no real android knowledge) and I am making this app for bluetooth communication.
It should receive the values, convert them to integers, do some math and display it in a textview.
The app receives four-digit integers from an esp32 board via bluetooth serial. It then does all kinds of stuff with it until a stringBuilder displays the value. I can update the text of a textView to the value of the string builder, but when I want to convert it to an actual integer, the app crashes. When I try to convert it to a classic string, it sometimes has a value, sometimes doesn’t. I’m not sure if in that case the value is null or there is some other problem, but nothing gets displayed. This null value behaviour is random, the crashing occurs every time.
The app i modified to this purpose is open source on github:
https://github.com/kai-morich/SimpleBluetoothTerminal
Could somebody take a look at it and tell me how it’s done?
I tried to convert the content of the stringbuilder to a string and that to an integer. I ‘ve tried some variations like external methods, or a few different approaches but all gave the same results. Mind you they were all rather basic. I have no idea what to do.
Edit: in the fragment_terminal.java script, the receive method is the one where i tried to modify.
Thanks in advance,

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
